# How write a hash function to make such expression to be true?

Tags: algorithm, hash

pseudocode:

<strike>`// deprecated x!=y && hash(x) == hash(y)  // how to make this true?`</strike>

`x!=y && hash(x) == hash(y) && (z!=x && z!=y) && (hash(x) != hash(z) && (hash(y) != hash(z)) // how to make this true?`

x and y can be any readable value

Whatever the language, the pseudocode is just help to understand what I mean.
I just wonder how to implement such hash function.

PS: For math, i am an idiot. I can not imagine if there is an algorithm that can do this.

**UPDATE 1: 
The pseudocode has bug, so I updated the code(actually still has bug, never mind, I will explain).**

My original requirement is to make a hash function that can return same value for  different parameter, and the parameter value should contains some rule. It means, only the parameter value in same category would gets same hash code, others are not.

e.g.

The following expressions are clearly(you can treat '0' as placeholder):

```
hash("1.1") == hash("1.0") == hash("0.1")
hash("2.2") == hash("2.0") == hash("0.2")
```

and

```
hash("2.2") != hash("2.1") != hash("1.2")
```

I think this question can do such description:

1. There are two or more different values contains implied same attribute.
2. Only these values have such same attribute in the world.
3. The attribute can obtain through some way(maybe a function), hash() will call it inside.
4. hash() one of the values, you can retrive the attribute, then you can get the unique hashCode.

It's looks like hash collision, but we exactly know what they are. Also looks like many-to-one model.

**How to design collision rules? The values could be any character or numeric.  And how to implement the designs?**

*PPS: This is a question full of bugs, maybe the updated parts cannot explain the the problem either. Or maybe this is a false proposition. I want abstract my issue as a general model, but it makes my mind overflowed. If necessary I will post my actual issue that I am facing.*

Comment: If I understand correctly (I don't think I do) you want to have an algorithm for `hash` function which will give same value for two different values `x` and `y` ?

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Different input returns same value. But my description is not strict, I will update it later.

Answer (score 2):

Any constant hash trivially satisfies your condition:

```
hash(v) = 42
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the  `&& (hash(x) != hash(z) && (hash(y) != hash(z))`

Answer (score 0):

A less constant answer than yuri kilocheck's would be to use the `mod` operator:

```
hash(v) = v % 10;
```

Then you'll have:

```
hash(1) = 1
hash(2) = 2
hash(3) = 3
...
hash(11) = 1
hash(12) = 2
```